# Connotations of "pertinacity"

Tags: nouns, connotation

Does the word *pertinacity* have positive or negative connotations?

Comment: Hi Mary, please try to use more descriptive question titles in the future. This is in your own interest — people simply won't click on vague titles such as "Language usage- connotations of words - synonyms" or "Usage: grammar or style". Cheers.

Comment: It's rare to see this word in normal English, so I'm not sure this question has a sensible answer.  Could you give us some more details?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It could mean both "resolute, firm in purpose", or it could mean "stubborn, unyielding".

It depends on the context, to determine what it really means.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pertinacity

Comment: _'Yes'_ (?) ...

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: it appears to have positive or negative connotations depending on circumstance, so "Yes" is clearly the right answer :-)

Comment: Oh, _clearly._ @Rhodri.

Comment: @mr. I don't know if I love or hate your comment. But surely yes.